# UWP/C# Frame Navigation Issues

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Sorry for the hashy title.
So, I have the following handler linked to a AppbarButton Settings button nested within NavigationView

```
private void SettingsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.SettingsPage));
    }
```

All it does currently is navigate to a Settings page that ive pre-defined. Now the issue i have is that i also have this above it which handles the navigationview selections

```
  private void NavView_SelectionChanged(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            NavigationViewItem item = args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem;

            switch (item.Tag.ToString())
            {
                case "OverView_Page":
                    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.Overview_Page));
                    break;
             }
        }
```

Distinct difference here is the ***ContentFrame*** part. It allows the required page to display as part of the navigationview.

The way ive done the SettingsButton_Click means that i loose the navigation menu when the button is clicked as its calling the Frame.Navigate instead of Content.Navigate.

I have tried to adjust the SettingsButton_Click to use ContentFrame.Navigate to no avail as it is actually an AppBarButton nested within NavigationView.

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Settings_Page" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="SettingsButton_Click"/>
```

Im not sure how to alter this to be a ContentFrame.Navigate instead of Frame.Navigate. Would you be able to help and see where im falling over?

EDIT:

As requested, MainPage.XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="BudgetSheet.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:local="using:BudgetSheet"
    xmlns:mux="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:muxcontrols="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    RequestedTheme="Dark">

    <Page.Resources>

    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource SystemBaseHighColor}"/>
                        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground"
                          BackgroundSource="Backdrop"
                          TintColor="#262626"
                          TintOpacity="0.8"
                          FallbackColor="#262626"/>
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <mux:NavigationView IsSettingsVisible="False" 
                            PaneTitle=" Budget Sheet Menu "                            
                            x:Name="NavView"                             
                            IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" 
                            PaneDisplayMode="LeftMinimal" 
                            AlwaysShowHeader="True"        
                            SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged"
                            Background="{StaticResource CustomAcrylicDarkBackground}">

            <mux:NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" UseLayoutRounding="False">
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Page2" Margin="0, 2, 1, 0" Tag="New_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" />
                    <AppBarButton Icon="OpenFile" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Open_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" />
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Save_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Settings_Page" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="SettingsButton_Click"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Calculator" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Calculator_Open" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" />
                </StackPanel>

                <mux:NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="HomeItem" 
                                        Content="HOME" 
                                        Tag="HOME_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>
                <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="OverviewItem" 
                                        Content="OVERVIEW" 
                                        Tag="OverView_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="BillsItem" 
                                        Content="BILLS" 
                                        Tag="Bills_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="PeopleItem" 
                                        Content="PEOPLE" 
                                        Tag="BillPayer_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="TransfersItem" 
                                        Content="TRANSFERS" 
                                        Tag="Transfers_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="PayDatesItem" 
                                        Content="PAY DATES" 
                                        Tag="PayDates_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>
            </mux:NavigationView.MenuItems>

            <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame">
                <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <NavigationThemeTransition/>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Frame.ContentTransitions>
            </Frame>

            <NavigationView.PaneFooter>
                <Button x:Name="ChangeUser" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" Foreground="#b880fc" >
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Contact" Margin="8"/>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right">      
                                    Change User
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </NavigationView.PaneFooter>
        </mux:NavigationView>
      </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: added mainpage xaml :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a property to the `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
public Frame TheContentFrame
{
    get => ContentFrame;
}
```

..you should be able to set the `Content` of the `ContentFrame` of the `MainPage` after you have got a reference to the `MainPage` using the `VisualTreeHelper` class:

```
private void SettingsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainPage mainPage = FindParent<MainPage>(this);
    if (mainPage != null)
        mainPage.TheContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.SettingsPage));
}

private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

    if (parent == null) return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ill give this a try!

Comment: Unfortunately doesnt work. It doesnt throw any errors but also doesnt navigate when pressing the button. Ill step through the code and see if i can figure it out though. Your helps appreciated :)

Comment: Are you getting a reference to MainPage? Is the SettingsButton_Click defined in NavigationView.xaml.cs?

Comment: It seems to be looping on FindParent and returning Null. SettingsButton_Click is defined within NavigationView yea :) By reference to MainPage what do you mean, Sorry. Im very new to this

Comment: Its geting to line if (mainPage != null) and then skipping the following line entirely. It doesnt execute at all.

Comment: Resolved it. Well, kinda. Im adding an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So, ive managed to navigate it with the following:

```
 private void SettingsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.SettingsPage));
        }
```

Now, this navigates successfully. It just doesnt minimise the navigation view after navigation. Im going to work out a solution for this and go from there

Thank you mm8 for everything so far

Basically went full circle on what i was trying to do initially bt it now works :(

edit:

Solved the minimise navigation view with the following:

```
 private void SettingsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {        
            ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.SettingsPage));
            NavView.IsPaneOpen = false;
       }
```

Comment: So the event handler is defined in the same view as the ContentFrame...? Why not call ContentFrame.Navigate directly then?

Comment: I tried this initially and it didnt work at all :/ Ive just dumped it in now and it works fine. I feel so stupid right now. Im not sure why its now working. Im still having issues with the NavView not minimising after selection but ill make a new post for that. Im going to keep your answer to hand above though as i know im going to need that later on

Comment: Im really sorry :(